# A question about the current value in a mains tester

Tags: voltage, tester

After reading [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/96101/how-does-the-tester-screwdriver-work) question, I simulated the tester as in the below circuit along with the current passing through human body:

[image]

Even I set the R_tester to  zero, the current still will be around 10μA which is too small for a neon bulb. This is due to the Xc being huge because of tiny human body capacitance.

The only way the current to become 0.5mA is to increase the capacitance to around at least 5nF.

But the references say that the human body capacitance is around 100pF in series with 1.5k resistor.

According to these assumptions it seems something is not quite true here.

What could be the problem with the model I've drawn above?[image]

Comment: You have a paralell branch to your R_body and C_body with just an R in the 1-100 kohm range, depending on person, humidity and so on, or simplify it to your R_body bein in paralell to C_body, it will get you close enough.

Comment: But it is modeled in series not in parallel: http://www.rfwireless-world.com/Articles/ESD-basics-and-ESD-tester.html What is parallel to what you meant?

Comment: Ah! For high frequency you are more interested in the series capacitance. For 50/60 Hz, you are mostly interested in the resistance. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human-body_model. 1k5 in parallel with 100 pF as a first order approximation.

Comment: see my edit. Should that be modelled this way? that makes sense if the human body model is RC parallel circuit instead of series.

Comment: I believe the problem is that the reference you are using is in error. If the body was modeled as a capacitor in series with a resistor, then no DC current could flow and DC sources would not be a hazard.  We know this is not true.  It makes much more sense for the body to be modeled as a resistor in parallel with a capacitor and then your issues would disappear.

Comment: @Barry, I think the series is correct. This is a model of non-grounded human body (i.e. intrinsic capacitance of human body when removed far from Earth or any return path).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a frequency of 50/60 Hz, the body capacitance is essentially an "open," so ignore it.  that leaves the 500k in series with the 1.5k body resistance.
Since the 500K is much larger than 1.5K, you can also temporarily ignore it, so you are left with the voltage source (250V) in series with the 500k, making it **a current source** of (250V/500K =) 0.5ma. This current, into the 1.5K body resistance develops (.5ma x 1.5K =) 0.75V max (with feet grounded).

Your model should be as you have it, except the resistor needs to be grounded and the capacitor removed (or in parallel with the body resistor).