# insulated wire giving shock

Tags: electricity, conductivity

I'm having some problems at my new girlfriend's house.
There was a extension cord that was giving shock and I changed to another. This one wasn't giving shock, but when I test it with that screwdriver that lights up a light on electricity, it lights up when touching the plastic part of the wire. The outside I mean.
And it is happening with all the extension cords of the house.

What I want to know is if it is normal to the outside part of the wire to conduct correct or if maybe there is a problem with the house electrical system.

English is not my primary language, sorry for any mistakes.

Edit: on the others extensions  of the house the light is on although it is very dim

Comment: that is not normal or safe... sounds like a possible missing neutral somewhere

Comment: You should get an electrician to look at the house. I'm not sure what could be causing that, but it sounds dangerous.

Comment: Please show a picture of the cords and tester in question.  Is the "screwdriver that lights up a light on electricity" a non-contact voltage tester?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vb35cxv7npuq4xi/IMG_20181012_223645.jpg?dl=0 I think it is.

Comment: need more info,  where does the shock happen? this isn't a male-male cable, is it? is the shock in the middle, by the connection, or maybe at the end?

Comment: This is a female-male cable. The shock is on the male plug. Then I tested with that tester ( how is it called?) and it turned on like the picture. The I tested the other extensions on other outlets and I was not getting any shock when I touch, but there is a dim light. I thought that the cables was isolates so no light should be on on the tester. This is a pic from another extension. https://www.dropbox.com/s/hwvfv61bhe9d1wq/IMG_20181012_225139.jpg?dl=0

Comment: is "that screwdriver" metal or plastic, and does it have a battery?"

Comment: The part that touches the wire is metal, it connects to a resistor and the resistor connects to a light. The light connects to a metal plate that touches the finger. Like this: https://img.lojadomecanico.com.br/IMAGENS/19/189/76541/Chave-de-Teste-com-Ponta-Fenda-18-x-3-Po-tramontina-419001101.JPG?ims=500x500

Comment: Those Neon testers are pretty sensitive and should not be your only test instrument.

Comment: New girlfriend = behave manly and try to fix everything. Sensible approach is think with your brain and not your trousers and get an electrician.

Comment: I'm sorry, I do work wirh electrical installation on buildings, have a course on it (not graduation though) but came here asking because I never saw something like that. Of course I'm trying to fix everything, but I have never seen the male plug giving shock. (Neither the outside of the cable with any live tension).      Is there any explanation on why the male plug was giving shock and lighting up the tester? The other wire lights a dim light and not give shock, but I thought that the insulation was to prevent that.

Comment: What test do you suggest? I have a digital multimeter and general tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get an electric shock when touching the *plug* of the extension lead then it is likely that the plug and/or the wiring inside is at fault. From the pictures you showed, I would suggest removing the old plug and replacing it with a good-quality new plug, also cutting back the wire to start in a new place.

A neon mains tester such as you showed in another picture works by you being a capacitor (this is normal, nothing to worry about). There is an explanation at [How does the tester screwdriver work?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/96101/36731)

I notice that the extension cord is only two wires. A safer version would have two wires with another insulator over them, like this:

[image]

([Image from the CPC website](https://cpc.farnell.com/pro-power/2192y-0-75mmwht50m/cable-flexible-2192y-0-75mm-wht/dp/CB11158))

However, what I **recommend** is to buy a new extension lead with a moulded-on plug and socket. This accomplishes two things: it will be safe, and it shows you care.

Answer (score 0):

If that “light-up” tester you are using is one to detect the PRESENCE of electricity without a physical connection to the wire then it is working correctly.

If that tester is one that requires a physical connection then there is an issue that has to be corrected - perhaps moisture on the surface could be the culprit...