Is it possible to have high volts with low amps?
Can you guys give me some example situations where you would have 200-10000++ volts but less than 0.031 amps? Is it even possible? If not, why?
Thanks.
edit: I just realised, police tasers. But somehow they kill even with 0.003 amps

Rub a balloon against your hair and you will have a voltage in that range and even lower current.

A milliamp at a kilovolt is typical for a photomultiplier.

Electro-chemistry research uses all kinds of less common voltage/current combinations.

What's special about 0.031 A?

Classic science class demonstration is the Van de Graaff generator that produces hundreds of kV at uA (a harmless current generally). Image from here.

It can produce less voltage, of course, and will produce less under load (including leakage and corona from pointy things in contact with the hemisphere).
Another example is the actual current of the electron beam in a CRT, which is something like 100uA if memory serves, however the short-circuit capability of the supply may be quite a bit higher so it's not safe to touch.

Neon test screwdrivers are mains voltage (~230 VAC) but low current (~0.5 mA).
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/96102/173919
